# SWIG issue with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, instance, swig

I have a problem with wrapping a member of a C++ class with SWIG.

I have a class which has a method that returns `map<int, postLib::nastran::element>`.

The class `postLib::nastran::element` in the interface file is:

```
class element {
public:
    element(void) ;
    element( const element &in) ;
    ~element(void) ;

    // data manipulation
    %feature("docstring", "getType()->int\n\tReturns an id corresponding to the TYPE of FE element") getType;
    int getType(void) const ;
    std::string  getTypeName(void) const ;
    int getNbrNodes(void) const ;
    int getNode(int index) const ;

    /*
    %extend {
            std::set<int>  getNodes(void) {
            const std::set<int> *siList;

            siList = &$self->getNodes();
            return *siList;
            }
    }*/
} ; //class element
```

My method looks like this:

```
PyObject * getEls(void) {
    std::map<int, postLib::nastran::element> els = $self->getElements();
    std::map<int, postLib::nastran::element>::iterator it;
    //PyObject * result = PyDict_New();
    PyObject * result = PyList_New(els.size());
    for (std::map<int, postLib::nastran::element>::iterator it=els.begin(); it!=els.end(); ++it) {
        PyObject * k = Py_BuildValue("i", (it->first)-1);
        postLib::nastran::element * e = &(it->second);
        //PyObject * v = Py_BuildValue("i", &(it->second));
        PyObject *v = SWIG_NewPointerObj((void *)e, SWIGTYPE_p_postLib__nastran__element, SWIG_POINTER_OWN);
        //PyDict_SetItem(result, k, v);
        PyList_SetItem(result, (it->first)-1, v );
        std::cout << typeid(&it->second).name()  << std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}
```

When I invoke the method getType() on element instances from Python I get following error message:

```
pure virtual method called
```

The element class inherits from another more generic element class that defines the getType as virtual.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used swig with Python language, but I have came across this error when making a Java wrapper, hope it's the same.

This error raises when from Python you call the getType member method because it is a C++ pure virtual method, this means it has no implementation and is intended to be overwritten/implemented by subclasses. So basically from Python you are invoking a not implemented method.

Does `postLib::nastran::element` declare the method as virtual and is equal to 0, something like:

```
virtual int getType(void) const = 0;
```

If it does then it is pure virtual and in your .i file haven't declare it that way. When SWIG encounters a class with pure virtual methods it does not generate constructors for that type (because you can't instantiate something that lacks implementation).

If the method is pure virtual then that class in intended to be subclassed. Swig can do this using the `directors` feature, so you can extend that C++ class from Python and use it.